# CakePHP 3 upgrade to 4 - Routing missing?

Tags: php, cakephp

i am trying to upgrade a CakePHP 3 project to CakePHP 4. Have gone through all the migration steps, which updates the files, but when i fire up the program it just displays:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Cake\Routing\Router" not found in C:\laragon\www\bakeboss\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\laragon\www\bakeboss\config\bootstrap.php(32): require() #1 C:\laragon\www\bakeboss\webroot\index.php(27): require('C:\\laragon\\www\\...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\bakeboss\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 26
```

If i go into the file that throws the error, it looks like this:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

/**
 * @var float
 */
define('TIME_START', microtime(true));

require CAKE . 'basics.php';

// Sets the initial router state so future reloads work.
Router::reload();
```

It is the "Router::reload();" that is causing the error, but as you can see, it does use the Routing\Router namespace, and my IDE can find the file and class just fine...? but for some reason, it doesn't work..?

Anyone have ideas on what i can try?

Comment: [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171208/cake-routing-router-not-found-in-shell-after-migration-to-cakephp-4)?

Comment: tried that, downloaded all files in the bin folder and replaced, but still the same error. Unless i have to do something more to "install" the files? I just downloaded and put into the bin folder..=

Comment: Probably your IDE reffers to declarations defined by composer, but if you wanna use router at runtime in this file, probably you should use code: `require_once "vendor/autoload.php"`. For debugging you can use function "class_exists()" to check if class is allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

in your bootstrap.php first load paths.php, autoload.php and bootstrap.php from Cake core:

```
require __DIR__ . '/paths.php';

// Use composer to load the autoloader.
require ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';

require CORE_PATH . 'config' . DS . 'bootstrap.php';

use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check if anything important from your app is missing. Here you can check the app skeleton of CakePHP 4.x - the most important file to check is `config/bootstrap.php`:
https://github.com/cakephp/app/tree/4.x

`composer update` and `composer dumpautoload -o` can also solve some autoloading issues. If classes are added or moved it is important to "tell" this composer autoloader by executing these two commands.